# Set "site_url" Config Variable in index.php

Tags: ee2-upgrades, focus-lab-master-config, config-overrides

I'm upgrading a multi-language site from EE1 to EE2, and it's using [the technique](http://www.slideshare.net/vinnyio/multilanguage-websites-in-expressionengine) of duplicating `index.php` and `path.php` inside subdirectories named for each language, and defining global language variables inside `path.php`.

So I upgraded the site to EE2, ditched the `path.php` files from the subdirectories, updated the `index.php` files to the new EE2 versions, and added these configuration variables:

```
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/en/';

$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    'country_code' => 'en',
    'language' => 'english'
);
```

The global variables seem to be working, but `site_url` is not. I tried:

- `$config['site_url'] = '...'`
- `$site_url = '...'`

I'm also using Focus Lab Master Config, and I made sure to comment out the `$env_config['site_url']` variable inside `config.master.php`. I also double-checked that it's not being defined inside `system/expressionengine/config/config.php`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** The `site_url` global variable works when used in templates, but it isn't applied in the control panel, in *Admin > General Configuration*, for example.

I'm using FocusLab Master Config, and assigning `site_url` from within `config.master.php` does update the control panel. So there must be something getting in the way somewhere between `index.php` and `config.master.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work when you hard code the site URL?

How about:

```
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = getenv('HTTP_HOST');
```

Have you ensured your system path has been altered in index.php?

```
$system_path = '../system';
```

Notice the extra leading dot.

Comment: Hard-coding the URL doesn't work either, and yes, the system path is correct.

Comment: How about trying to append the /en/ if you have a sub-directory setup: $site_url = "http://www.domain.com/en/"; ?

Comment: Also, check what's in your database (set via the control panel) as assign_to_config[] might not be overriding that setting the same way that config[] does in config.php

Comment: hmm...odd. I was basing my question off of the fact that the Site URL in the control panel's General Configuration section wasn't changing, but I just checked my template output, and the `{site_url}` variable is outputting the correct URL for all languages and the naked homepage URL. I don't understand why the config variable isn't updating the control panel/DB setting though - I thought that was the whole point?

Comment: Is it not updated in both Admin > General Configuration and in Admin > System Administration > Config File Editor? I've not used the Focus Lab Master Config before but check to make sure nothing in there is overriding those values.

Comment: There do seem to be a lot of issues relating to [values not being overridden in the CP](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/12866/). I know a few feature requests have previously been submitted on the subject too but unfortunately from that point it goes into a black hole within EllisLab and you never know what's been worked on and when. It's always just a case of wait and see but these things are never done quickly.

Comment: If I set the `site_url` variable inside `config.master.php`, it updates in the CP. So there must be something between `index.php` and Master Config that's preventing that variable from being assigned...